# docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* files ignored on docker-compose first run

Tags: postgresql, docker, docker-compose, docker-entrypoint

I try to setup a Postgresql db in my docker-compose and it worked as expected for a moment. But now, my migration sql scripts aren't runned anymore, even after a fresh new build (`sudo docker-compose build` or `sudo docker-compose up --build`) and after removing the persistent volume created locally (`sudo rm -rf db-data`).

```
$ sudo docker-compose up
[+] Running 14/14
 ⠿ db Pulled                                                                                                                                                                                        10.7s
   ⠿ a2abf6c4d29d Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      2.6s
   ⠿ e1769f49f910 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      2.8s
   ⠿ 33a59cfee47c Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      2.9s
   ⠿ 461b2090c345 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      3.1s
   ⠿ 8ed8ab6290ac Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      3.4s
   ⠿ 495e42c822a0 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      3.5s
   ⠿ 18e858c71c58 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      3.6s
   ⠿ 594792c80d5f Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      3.7s
   ⠿ 794976979956 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      8.2s
   ⠿ eb5e1a73c3ca Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      8.3s
   ⠿ 6d6360292cba Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      8.3s
   ⠿ 131e916e1a28 Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      8.4s
   ⠿ 757a73507e2e Pull complete                                                                                                                                                                      8.5s
[+] Running 2/2
 ⠿ Container db-1   Created                                                                                                                                                       0.2s
 ⠿ Container app-1  Created                                                                                                                                                       0.1s
Attaching to app-1, db-1
db-1   | The files belonging to this database system will be owned by user "postgres".
db-1   | This user must also own the server process.
db-1   | 
db-1   | The database cluster will be initialized with locale "en_US.utf8".
db-1   | The default database encoding has accordingly been set to "UTF8".
db-1   | The default text search configuration will be set to "english".
db-1   | 
db-1   | Data page checksums are disabled.
db-1   | 
db-1   | fixing permissions on existing directory /var/lib/postgresql/data ... ok
db-1   | creating subdirectories ... ok
db-1   | selecting dynamic shared memory implementation ... posix
db-1   | selecting default max_connections ... 100
db-1   | selecting default shared_buffers ... 128MB
db-1   | selecting default time zone ... Etc/UTC
db-1   | creating configuration files ... ok
db-1   | running bootstrap script ... ok
db-1   | performing post-bootstrap initialization ... ok
db-1   | syncing data to disk ... ok
db-1   | 
db-1   | 
db-1   | Success. You can now start the database server using:
db-1   | 
db-1   |     pg_ctl -D /var/lib/postgresql/data -l logfile start
db-1   | 
db-1   | initdb: warning: enabling "trust" authentication for local connections
db-1   | You can change this by editing pg_hba.conf or using the option -A, or
db-1   | --auth-local and --auth-host, the next time you run initdb.
db-1   | waiting for server to start....2022-01-26 14:57:29.498 UTC [49] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.506 UTC [49] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.529 UTC [50] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-26 14:57:29 UTC
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.542 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
db-1   |  done
db-1   | server started
db-1   | CREATE DATABASE
db-1   | 
db-1   | 
db-1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/00000000000000_diesel_initial_setup
db-1   | 
db-1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2021-10-21-140200_initial_schemes
db-1   | 
db-1   | /usr/local/bin/docker-entrypoint.sh: ignoring /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/2022-01-24-120647_fill_tables
db-1   | 
db-1   | waiting for server to shut down...2022-01-26 14:57:29.858 UTC [49] LOG:  received fast shutdown request
db-1   | .2022-01-26 14:57:29.865 UTC [49] LOG:  aborting any active transactions
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.868 UTC [49] LOG:  background worker "logical replication launcher" (PID 56) exited with exit code 1
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.868 UTC [51] LOG:  shutting down
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.914 UTC [49] LOG:  database system is shut down
db-1   |  done
db-1   | server stopped
db-1   | 
db-1   | PostgreSQL init process complete; ready for start up.
db-1   | 
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.993 UTC [1] LOG:  starting PostgreSQL 14.1 (Debian 14.1-1.pgdg110+1) on x86_64-pc-linux-gnu, compiled by gcc (Debian 10.2.1-6) 10.2.1 20210110, 64-bit
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.994 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv4 address "0.0.0.0", port 5432
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:29.994 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on IPv6 address "::", port 5432
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:30.008 UTC [1] LOG:  listening on Unix socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:30.026 UTC [63] LOG:  database system was shut down at 2022-01-26 14:57:29 UTC
db-1   | 2022-01-26 14:57:30.038 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
```

As you can see, my docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/* files are all being ignored. Notice that my 3 migrations scripts run fine on a local pg instance.

My docker-compose looks lik this:

```
version: '3.7'

services:
    db:
        image: postgres
        restart: always
        environment:
          - POSTGRES_USER=***
          - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=***
          - POSTGRES_DB=***
        ports:
          - '5433:5432'
        volumes: 
          - ./db-data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
          - ./migrations:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/ # copy the sql migrations

[...]

volumes:
    db-data:
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [poatgres image entrypoint](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/a83005b407ee6d810413500d8a041c957fb10cf0/14/bullseye/docker-entrypoint.sh#L156) only below file type executed:

- *.sh
- *.sql
- *.sql.gz
- *.sql.xz